# What should happen if a live hot wire touched the side of a metal device box?

Tags: electrical

Assume you have a metal device box, correctly installed with 14/3 cable incoming and a three-way  ungrounded light switch installed. Assume that the box is correctly grounded using the ground wire attached to the ground screw of the box.

No other connections exist in the box.

What should happen if one of the hot screw terminals gets close enough to the side of the box — say you were pushing the switch back into the box while it was energized and the side of the switch got close enough to the metal box to make contact?

Would you expect an arc? Would it trip the circuit breaker for that circuit back in the panel?

Comment: yes and yes....

Comment: An arc/spark(If not push together very fast) at least, more than likely a breaker trip also, unless very fast to separate them.  It is a good reason not to work on live power.  Just imagine the fun if it was your hand touching hot and grounded box.

Comment: Yes to both as the other commenters have said, but at least you will have figured out which breaker controls power to this device!

Comment: Absolutely nothing, because you had the breaker turned off while doing that work?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  of course!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   And he took pictures of everything before any rework was done. :-)

Comment: @JACK this is actually a hypothetical from a conversation that happened more than a month ago….

Comment: I'd expect an arc flash which is when shit gets real. Some of my pliers are missing chunks. But I still have both my eyes because I wear safety glasses religiously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the contact was quick enough, "brushing" the two side by side, you'd have an arc and the breaker might trip, it might not.

If the contact was more definite, you pushed the switch into the side of the box making hard contact, you probably wouldn't see an arc but the two surfaces would weld together, you'd hear a pop and the breaker would/should trip.

Comment: Does the breaker flavor (e.g., AFCI, GFCI) affect the expected behavior of the system?

Comment: Yes, both those breakers if installed would operate much faster that a normal breaker and would reduce any arcs that might occur.  If they were individual outlets, they would trip before the circuit breaker.